# Per mille symbol in classicthesis style

Tags: fonts, symbols, mathpazo

I need the *per mille* (`\textperthousand`) symbol in math mode and text in a  `classicthesis` style document. Instead, in the PDF, I get a percent symbol followed by a small, black square.

For example, this LaTeX code

```
For example, for carbon-13,
\[
\delta^{13}{\textrm C} =
\left(
\frac{ \left( \frac{^{13}\textrm C}{^{12}\textrm C} \right) _{sample}- \left(\frac{^{13}\textrm C}{^{12}\textrm C}\right)_{standard}}%
{\left(\frac{^{13}\textrm C}{^{12}\textrm C}\right)_{standard}}%
\right) \times 1000 \qquad\textperthousand
\]
This value, represented by a delta ($\delta$) prefixing the mass number and symbol for the element, is in parts per thousand or \emph{permil} (\textperthousand).
```

produces correct output when typeset using PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX using the `article` style
but not when typeset using PDFLaTeX with the `classicthesis` style.

Is there something I can do to obtain the correct symbol?

Comment: `\usepackage{wasysym}` provides `\permil` which gives you the same symbol. Does that help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than a `classicthesis` problem it's a font problem. The style uses the `mathpazo` package that sets the main font to Palatino. Try loading also the `textcomp` package. Note also that you should say `\text{\textperthousand}`, in order to avoid warning messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\textperthousand` command is available both with the T1 encoding (used by `classicthesis`) and the TS1 encoding.

However, the Palatino font loaded via the `mathpazo` package by `classicthesis` hasn't the required glyph: in the T1 encoding `\textperthousand` is built by adding a small zero next to `%` and the small zero is missing (a black square is used to show this).

However the Palatino text companion font has the glyph `\textperthousand`, so all you need to do is to load `textcomp`: add

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

to your document preamble.

Note that `\textperthousand` is not legal in math mode and produces a warning. You can avoid it by using

```
\mbox{\textperthousand}
```

or, better, by loading also `amsmath` and using

```
\text{\textperthousand}
```

You may want to define a variant command that works both in text and math mode:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\perthousand}{%
  \ifmmode
    \text{\textperthousand}%
  \else
    \textperthousand
  \fi}
```