# Math object doesn't display %

Tags: math-mode, symbols, open-office

Typing the formula

> `C.I._{95%}`

doesn't display the `%` symbol in the document. It looks just how

> C.I._95

would be displayed.

Background: When creating a OpenOffice formula as math object `%` is often used for special symbols, e.g. `%alpha` displays the proper Greek symbol. Maybe it's assuming I'm trying to get it to be something else?

Research:

> `C.I._{95%perthousand}`

displays properly (the one that looks like 0/oo).

How do I get the `%` symbol to show up?

Comment: Do you just want `\%`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In TeX the percent sign `%` begins a comment extending over the whole line. To escape it use `\%` instead.

Answer (score 7):

## Remarks

By default the `%`-symbol is the symbol used to make a comment. To display the symbol you have to "escape" it by prefixing it with `\`, i.e. `\%`.
The same applies for other symbols, e.g. `\$`, `\{` or `\}`.

The implementation to get the permille symbol was taken from @egreg's answer in [Per mille symbol in classicthesis style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123592/per-mille-symbol-in-classicthesis-style).

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\perthousand}{%
    \ifmmode
        \text{\textperthousand}%
    \else
        \textperthousand
    \fi}
\begin{document}
$C.I._{95\%}$
$C.I._{95\perthousand}$
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]