# How to write percentile symbol in latex?

Tags: symbols

I want to write percentile (‰) symbol in latex. I've tried \‰ but it can't

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. `\textperthousand` in text mode.

Comment: That's not the percentile symbol. That's permille.

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) also mentions the ``\permil`` command from ``wasysym``, in case you prefer the style.

Comment: Take a look at this question [per mille symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123592/per-mille-symbol-in-classicthesis-style)

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice answer in [this page](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/latexpermille/):

- `\textperthousand` from the package `textcomp`, also provides `\textpertenthousand` but both only work in text mode, not in math mode.
- `\permil` from the package `wasysym`, works in both text mode as in math mode.

For example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

Let's try different per milles:

\textperthousand  \ (textcomp package in text mode)

\permil \ (wasysym package in text mode)

$\frac{1}{7}\permil$ (wasysym package in math mode)\\


\textpertenthousand (extra bonus)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ConTeXt users can use one of the following methods. The `\unit` method works best when it is used in combination with a number because it adds a small space between both.

```
\starttext

1\,‰ \quad 1\,\perthousand \quad \unit{1 permille}

\stoptext
```

[image]